# Scala dbc update statement

Tags: scala, jdbc

Where can I see example of scala.dbc update statement?
I have found select statement example only...

```
select fields (
                ("url" of characterVarying(32)) and
                ("name" of characterVarying(32)) and
                ("last_update" of integer)) from ("feeds")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A search turned up [this old wiki page](http://scala.sygneca.com/libs/dbc?rev=1179662768), I haven't tested it though. As other people have mentioned in the past, there are possibly more up to date / actively maintained [database persistence options for scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362748/wanted-good-examples-of-scala-database-persistence).

Comment: Thanks. I have made task using jdbc.